# Different content download size for Azure app service and Azure Linux VM

Tags: java, azure, rest

I have a Java spring boot application using Jetty which is deployed in Azure App service(Plan: P3v2). The same is also deployed in a Azure linux VM (Standard DS4 v2 [8 vcpus, 28 GiB memory]) with Cent OS operating system.

I have an API that returns around 30 mb in uncompressed format.
I have enabled gzip for both Azure App Service as well as the VM.

When I hit the API the compressed content size of the response from Azure app service is 3.2 MB and that from the VM is 1.6MB.

What could be the reason for this difference?